# C++ passing function's result to another function

Tags: c++, function, quadratic

I've tried to check resources online but don't seem to quite manage to pass the result from a function into a 2nd one. I coded a program to solve the quadratic formula and need to use the discriminant (returned in the first function **calculateDiscriminant**) as an argument to the second function (**quadraticFormula**). How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> 
using namespace std;


double calculateDiscriminant(double a, double b, double c) {
    double discriminant;

    discriminant = pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c);
    
    return discriminant;
     }

void quadraticFormula(double discriminant, double a, double b, double c) {
    double result1;
    double result2;
    double result3;
    double discriminant = calculateDiscriminant(double a, double b, double c); //I feel my problem lies here
   

    if (discriminant > 0) {
        result1 = (-b + sqrt(discriminant))/(2 * a);
        result2 = (-b - sqrt(discriminant))/(2 * a);
        cout << "There are 2 solutions." << endl;
        cout << "The solutions are: " << result1 << " and " << result2;
    }
    else if (discriminant == 0) {
        result3 = (-b)/(2 * a);
        cout << "There is 1 solution." << endl;
        cout << "The solution is: " << result3;
        
    }
    else if (discriminant < 0) {
        cout << "There is no solution.";
    } }

int main() {
    
    double userInput1;
    double userInput2;
    double userInput3;
    double discriminant;
    
    cout << "Please enter the values of a, b, and c: " << endl;
    cin >> userInput1 >> userInput2 >> userInput3;
    
    calculateDiscriminant(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);
    quadraticFormula(discriminant, userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);
    
    return 0; }
```

Comment: Do you know how to call a function?

Comment: `discriminant = calculateDiscriminant(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);`

Comment: Look at your `main` function and how functions are called, and compare it to the line you have doubts about.  Do you see the difference in how a function is supposed to be called?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up the syntax to *declare* a function, with the syntax to *call* a function. But these are quite different things, try this

```
double discriminant = calculateDiscriminant(a, b, c);
```

Think about it this way, when you decalre a function you have to tell the compiler all the types, so

```
double calculateDiscriminant(double a, double b, double c) {
```

tells the compiler that `calculateDiscriminant` is a function with the `double` parameters that also returns a `double`. Now you've told the compiler that you don't need to repeat the information every time you call the function, so just

```
calculateDiscriminant(a, b, c)
```

is all you need to call the function. Strange this is that you got this right in every other function call in the program, so I'm not sure why you tried to do it differently here.

You have some other errors. In `main` this

```
double discriminant;

cout << "Please enter the values of a, b, and c: " << endl;
cin >> userInput1 >> userInput2 >> userInput3;

calculateDiscriminant(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);
quadraticFormula(discriminant, userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);
```

should be this

```
cout << "Please enter the values of a, b, and c: " << endl;
cin >> userInput1 >> userInput2 >> userInput3;

quadraticFormula(userInput1, userInput2, userInput3);
```

Not sure why you are trying to call `calculateDiscriminant` twice. You don't need to.

And this

```
void quadraticFormula(double discriminant, double a, double b, double c) {
```

should be this

```
void quadraticFormula(double a, double b, double c) {
```

You are calculating the discriminant in the `quadraticFormula` function, so you don't need to pass it as parameter as well.

You should think about function parameters logically. A function that is calculating a quadratic formula needs three parameters, the coefficients of the three terms in the quadratic equation. If you find yourself writing a quadratic formula function that takes four parameters you are doing something wrong. That's simple logic, nothing to do with C++.

Answer (score -2):

```
void quadraticFormula(double a, double b, double c) '
```

//You Dont need 4th parameter

```
 {
        double result1;
        double result2;
        double result3;
        double var1=a; //here
        double var2=b; //here
        double var3=c; //here
```

//Assign Values from Parameters to Variables

```
    `double discriminant1=calculateDiscriminant(var1,var2,var3);`
```

//just pass values to the fucntion **calculateDiscriminant()**

```
    if (discriminant1 > 0) {
        result1 = (-var2 + sqrt(discriminant1))/(2 * var1);
        result2 = (-var2 - sqrt(discriminant1))/(2 * var1);
        cout << "There are 2 solutions." << endl;
        cout << "The solutions are: " << result1 << " and " << result2;
    }
    else if (discriminant1 == 0) {
        result3 = (-var2)/(2 * var1);
        cout << "There is 1 solution." << endl;
        cout << "The solution is: " << result3;
        
    }
    else if (discriminant1 < 0) {
        cout << "There is no solution.";
    } }
```

Comment: Using a global variable like this is very bad practice. Please do not do this!

Comment: @doomista, you can also do it this way.I edited the Code

Comment: Please don't post only the corrected code. The helpful part is the explanation on what needs to change and why, as that will help preventing the issue in the future!

Comment: @JVApen, Got your point. I'll edit it . But do appreciate work

Comment: @JVApen, Its Done

Comment: I think it still needs a bit more, explaining the why, not the how